# AdView Force closes

Tags: android, admob, adview

I added a admob AdView to my layout but after adding my app force closes what might be the reason.

Have I done something wrong plz correct me. Without that adView my app works perfectly.

or do I have to add anything in the main_activity file?

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/cyan" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout01"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="914dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
            android:text="TECHNICAL\nENGLISH -I"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="185dp"
            android:text="ENGINEERING\nPHYSICS I"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="250dp"
            android:text="ENGINEERING\nCHEMISTRY I"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="315dp"
            android:text="COMPUTER\nPROGRAMMING"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="380dp"
            android:text="ENGINEERING\nGRAPHICS"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="445dp"
            android:text="COMPUTER\nPRGRAMMING LAB"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView8"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="510dp"
            android:text="ENGINEERING\nPRACTICES LAB"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView9"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="575dp"
            android:text="PHYSICS\nCHEMISTRY LAB"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="200dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="65dp"
            android:entries="@array/Grade"
            android:prompt="@string/hello_world"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="200dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="110dp"
            android:entries="@array/Grade"
            android:prompt="@string/hello_world"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="200dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="175dp"
            android:entries="@array/Grade"
            android:prompt="@string/hello_world"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="200dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="240dp"
            android:entries="@array/Grade"
            android:prompt="@string/hello_world"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="200dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="305dp"
            android:entries="@array/Grade"
            android:prompt="@string/hello_world"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="200dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="370dp"
            android:entries="@array/Grade"
            android:prompt="@string/hello_world"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="200dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="435dp"
            android:entries="@array/Grade"
            android:prompt="@string/hello_world"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner8"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="200dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="500dp"
            android:entries="@array/Grade"
            android:prompt="@string/hello_world"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner9"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="200dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="565dp"
            android:entries="@array/Grade"
            android:prompt="@string/hello_world"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView11"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="SEMESTER I - GPA CALCULATOR"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="75dp"
            android:text="MATHEMATICS - I"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView9"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="37dp"
            android:text="CALCULATE" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

       <LinearLayout

           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
           android:layout_marginTop="58dp"
           android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
           android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView8" >

           <com.google.ads.AdView
               android:id="@+id/adView"
               android:layout_width="fill_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               ads:adSize="BANNER"
               ads:adUnitId="a15325d1ef2568c"
               ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
               ads:testDevices="TEST_DEVICE_ID" >
           </com.google.ads.AdView>

       </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Can you post the log cat?

Comment: Please post AndroidManifest.xml